# Low Bandwidth Streaming Issues

Tags: memory, gstreamer, buffering, imx6, low-bandwidth

Hi I have imx6 board connected to a 1080p, 60fps camera source.
There are gstreamer pipelines which are build to render streaming and video recording sessions from this camera source.

The Streams are at `1080p`, `30fps` , encoding bitrate of around `16000 kbps ( h264 )`.
I assume that the bandwidth to send this data over is network is around 16mbps minimum - Just to Stream it.

If I need to also send the video recording data over the network then it would be double the required bandwidth - around 32 mbps
minimum .

Now If the bandwidth is around `8 mbps or 5 mbps`, then I see that

1. There are lot of frames that are dropped
2. Over a period of time , the application which is serving these, goes to a blank screen ( no UI refresh ) and we need to restart the imx6 board to overcome this situation

When the network is not enough to send the data, the data is buffered on the imx6 board, which causes lot of memory being eaten up and hence the system could be irresponsive . How to conclude this point ? Like looking at the pipeline elements of gstreamer which might buffer - any suggestion would help us to understand this better ?

Also in the gstreamer pipeline, we have lot of elements like `queue` elements with `max-size-buffers` set to 5 , 2 etc.
`"leaky"` is not configured . To avoid buffering in low bandwidth does setting of "leaky" element help ?

Comment: One of the issues were in similar description mentioned here
https://www.thegoodpenguin.co.uk/blog/finding-a-memory-leak-in-a-large-and-complex-gstreamer-pipeline/